# Extract timestamps of frames from mp4 video using FFMPEG and NOT ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract the timestamps of mp4 video using ffmpeg.

With ffprobe it is like following.

command: `ffprobe -v quiet -f lavfi -print_format json -i "movie=test.mp4" -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time`

Following is the output with ffprobe but same I need using ffmpeg:

`{
    "frames": [
        {
            "pkt_pts_time": "0.000000"
        },
        {
            "pkt_pts_time": "0.033367"
        },
        {
            "pkt_pts_time": "0.066733"
        }
    ]
}`

I need using ffmpeg because I have to use ffmpeg.js(https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js) lib at browser side where requirement is to extract timestamp of frames.

Comment: Note that this project is very outdated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`showinfo`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showinfo) filter which prints a line for each frame:

```
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x7ff710000000] n:   1 pts:      1 pts_time:0.04    pos:       -1 fmt:rgb24 sar:1/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:C4740AD1 plane_checksum:[C4740AD1] mean:[127] stdev:[125.7]
```

Here, the `pts_time` is the presentation timestamp of the frame. Run it, for example, like so:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f lavfi -i testsrc -filter:v showinfo -f null /dev/null
```